# Installing VS Shell Isolated on Windows 8.1 using SCCM 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2013, deployment, sccm

First off, I know about the bug that happens when installing Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1 using SCCM 2012. However, I believe this bug was fixed in the update 3. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2014/10/29/error-26403-failed-to-add-user-to-group.aspx

I have downloaded and installed Visual Studio Premium 2013 with update 4.

I have downloaded the latest available version of the Visual Studio 2013 Shell (Isolated). https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx. And when installing with SCCM 2012, I am still getting the error message that was present in pre-update 3 versions of visual studio.

`Error 26403.Failed to add user to group.  (-2147463168   SYSTEM Performance Log Users   )`

Does anyone have a workaround for installing Vs Shell (Isolated) onto a windows 8.1 machine with sccm 2012 ?

Comment: Are you installing as the system or as a user?  The error message is consistent with running the installer as the system account which VS might not support.

Comment: System account. Ideally I'd like to be able to publish the advertisement and install with or without a user logged in.

Comment: Whether that's possible really depends on the application's installer not SCCM.  I think your questions really boils down to "How can I perform an unattended install of VS Shell Isolated?"  The answer will be the same regardless of whether you're using SCCM or some other means of software distribution.